# How to load data on a screen on the press of a button without routing and rebuilding whole screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Pardon me if this is a naive question but I am trying to figure out a way in Flutter to load different data when the user clicks a button. The way I currently see is routing the user to a new screen everytime but I am sure there would be a better approach without loading the whole screen everytime

Comment: This is kind of what i am trying out https://i.imgur.com/VYl44Ds.png

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use a Stateful Widget

I would create a Future Builder / ListView Builder. Depending on how you want it to behave you could have the ListView items clear before regenerating the list of items to show.

Future Builder you could create a function to return certain widgets depending on the request you make with the function.